# How to validate a Facebook Messenger Message?

Tags: facebook, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot

I have created a Facebook Messenger Bot with DialogFlow (old Api.ai). Facebook Messenger drops any invalid message coming from a bot. For example, a list message with five elements. However, sometimes it is hard to figure out the error. Is there a way to validate the messages or to see the reason of the drop?

My specific problem comes when I try to send a list with elements with a postback button. Sometimes it pass and the message appears but some others the message is filtered. However, if I remove the postback button from every element it always passes.

Any idea? Thanks!!

Comment: Can you provide the message JSON that isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about api.ai, but you can see the reason of the message drop in the Fb response you get. In case of an error, you get a HTTP 400 like:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Invalid keys \"messenger_extansions\" were found in param \"name_placeholder[elements][0][buttons][1]\"
    }
}
```